# Mongoose array of undefined number of objects Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm working on quiz app that uses Mongoose and Express server to store my quizes, but I got a problem with defining Mongoose Schema for quiz.

I found out I can use a SubSchema for this, but I still don't know how to define an Array with undefined number of objects inside it.

How to make a schema that can store these quizes? For example one quiz contains only 2 questions, and the next one contains for example 12 questions.

There is my Schema that needs to be complete, could someone explain me how to do it?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const quizSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        min: 8,
        max: 64,
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now(),
    },
    data: {
        type: Array,
    },
})

module.exports = new mongoose.model('quiz', quizSchema)
```

Comment: data:[{String}], it will define an array of strings.

Comment: so data: [{Object}] will define array of objects?

Comment: The array is already an array of objects, you just need to tell what kind of value you will store in those objects.

Comment: okay it works, but i get an id for every object inside an array got it's own ID, it's needed or it's a bug?